# Check if current time is given time

Tags: c#

In my main method I'm constantly checking if given time is equal to current time. But my code seems to fail. This is a windows forms application, not a console application. Not trying to convert string to time span, need some way of checking if two times are equal.

```
static void Main()
{
    TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.Parse("10:09:00");
    while (true)
    {

        TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        if (now == start)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Fount at " + now + " " + start);
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Running Loop at " + now + " "+start);
    }
}
```

I tried altering the first line as,

```
TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.Parse("10:09:00:0000000");
```

That doesn't seem to work either, Can anybody suggest me a better way?

Comment: How do you check seconds?

Comment: @Justcode I'm checking seconds as `00` in `10:09:00`

Comment: @Nishin But `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay` isn't.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay` has `00:00:00:0000000` format, that is why i changed my code to `TimeSpan.Parse("10:09:00:0000000")` @John

Comment: @Nishin re-read what I said: your code now asks "is 10:09:12:134532" equal to "10:09:00:000000".

Comment: You do realize that DateTime and TimeSpan objects have millisecond (or better) precision. It's very possible that the current time (as you calculate it) will never be exactly equal to your `start`. Instead, subtract the two times and check that the result is "close enough" to call them equal

Comment: Side note: "This is a windows forms application" - this is absolutely not how one writes event-driven program... normally your program should be terminated by Windows due to misbehaving before it gets  to wait for more than a minute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work since you compare different timespans, and when you add fractional milliseconds it's unlikely they will match.

You can use the following code snippet to compare time:

```
    TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(11, 49, 0);
    while (true)
    {
        TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        if (Math.Abs((now - start).TotalMilliseconds)<1000)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Found at " + now + " " + start);
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Running Loop at " + now + " " + start);
    }
```

Comment: I think i like your approach better, upvote

Comment: Worked!. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Why does everyone seem to like initializing TimeSpans by parsing a string. That struct has an hour, min, sec constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is probably the milliseconds

You could also use an extension to trim, which will give you a truncated time up to the second

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static DateTime TrimMilliseconds(this DateTime dt)
    {
        return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second, 0, dt.Kind);
    }
}
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y7RNcO)

Answer (score 2):

Your "start" value is OK, the problem is that `TimeOfDay` will include much more precision than minutes. You need to somehow truncate the value down to minutes.

This is one such way you could do that:

```
var now = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Floor(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds));
```

TotalSeconds will return a non-integer value (i.e. it will include milliseconds as a fraction), so we take that value, floor it to remove the fraction component, and then convert it back into seconds - now without any values shorter than a second.

Of course you can switch out "Seconds" for Minutes, Hours, etc. as necessary.

Comment: Upvotes all round, neater floor, although does he really want minutes?

Comment: @TheGeneral It looks that way, but OP can adjust to taste :-)